# Prove $-|x|$ is semiconcave function

Tags: proof-verification, partial-differential-equations

Reading Evan's, in the example $(51)$ at page 136, there's written $-|x|$ is a **semiconcave** function, according to the definition

\begin{align}
g(x+z) -2g(x)+g(x-z) \leq C |z|^2
\end{align}

for every $x,z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $C>0$.  I know this is equivalent to as for  the concavity of the function $z \mapsto g(z)-\frac{C}{2}|z|^2$

But in my example the problem is at $x=0$, which is not a differentiable point for my function.
Up to now, I know that $|x|$ in *not* semiconcave in every open set containing $x=0$, since by taking $x=0$ in the definition I can't find a $C>0$ that satisfies the bound.

I'd like to be sure that my reasoning is correct for the $-|x|$ case.

---

Again, applying the definition, I have to show that exists some $C>0$ such that

\begin{align}
|x+z|-2|x|+|x-z| > C|z|^2
\end{align}

but I don't know how.

Of course, I know that $-|x|$ is concave ($|x|$ is convex) and hence it's semiconcave, but I'd like to use the definition.

Comment: Why do you need differentiability? At $x=0$ the definition becomes $g(z)+g(-z) \leq C|z|^2$, i.e., $-2|z| \leq C|z|^2$. This holds for *every* nonnegative $C$.

Comment: Yes, but this has to hold for every $x,z \in \mathbb{R}^N$

Comment: Well I only mentioned $x=0$ because that seemed to be the sticking point for you. Away from $x=0$ your function is differentiable. Have you found a constant $C$ that works for all $x\neq 0$ and all $z$?

Comment: No, thats my problem !

Comment: I'm confused, surely if $x=0$ you have $g(z)-2g(0) +g(-z) = -2|z| \le 0$?

Comment: @kccu I can say that since away from $x=0$ it's differentiable, then I use the characterization I mentioned in the question, does it work for you?

Comment: @copper.hat yes, and holds that $-2|z| \leq C |z|^2$ , $C>0$ for every $z$.  But I want a bound also for every $x \ne 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is convex, we have $f(x) = f({1 \over 2} ((x+z)+(x-z))  \le {1 \over 2} (f(x+z)+f(x-z))$.

Letting $f(x) = |x|$ we obtain
$|x| \le {1 \over 2} (|x+z|+|x-z|)$, and so
$2g(x) \ge g(x+z)+g(x-z)$ from which you obtain the desired answer with $C=0$.

Comment: $C$ has to be strictly positive

Comment: Then take $C=1$??? If it works for $C=0$ it will work for any $C' \ge C$.

Comment: Sorry I read to fast! Thanks!